# Paypal sdk for the tutorial

Tags: php, paypal, parallel-processing

Im trying to make an parallel Payment with paypal, 
I have followed the tutorial : [Paypal Adaptive Payments - Parallel Payments JSON Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPFFIuydHn4)
but he is depending on classes I dont have, like class "App" and other methods I dont have.
I tried looking for the classes but I couldent find them
Where can I get all those class from ?

Thanks